# How do I use the Bol.com API to GET Search Volumes?

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

My goal is to get Search Volumes from Bol.com using the Bol.com API from words in my Google Sheet.

For this I am using the following Script:

```
function getSearchVolumesFromSheet() {
  // Vervang hieronder "API_KEY" door je eigen Bol.com API-sleutel.
  var apiKey = "IPUTMUAPIKEYHEREBUTREDACTEDFORPRIVACYPURPOSES";
  
  // Vervang "Sheet1" door de naam van het blad waarop de zoektermen zich bevinden.
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  
  // Haal de zoektermen op uit de eerste kolom.
  var searchTerms = sheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues().flat();
  
  // Roep de Bol.com API aan voor elke zoekterm en verzamel de zoekvolumes in een array.
  var searchVolumes = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < searchTerms.length; i++) {
    var searchTerm = searchTerms[i][0];
    var url = "https://api.bol.com/catalog/v4/search/?q=" + encodeURIComponent(searchTerm) + "&dataoutput=SEARCH_VOL_PLUS";
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + apiKey
      }
    });
    var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    var productSearchVolumes = data.products.map(function(product) {
      return product.search_volume;
    });
    searchVolumes.push(productSearchVolumes);
  }
  
  // Schrijf de zoekvolumes naar de tweede kolom van het blad.
  sheet.getRange(1, 2, searchVolumes.length, searchVolumes[0].length).setValues(searchVolumes);
}
```

I tried this script but I got the following error:

> Exception: Request failed for https://api.bol.com returned code 400
>
> getSearchVolumesFromSheet
>
> @ Code.gs:16

Looking on the bol.com API Documentation, I am not getting any wiser. What can I try next?

Comment: About `Looking on the bol.com API Documentation, I am not getting any wiser. What can I try next?`, can you provide the official document of the API you want to use?

Comment: Hi Tanaike, Here you go: https://api.bol.com/retailer/public/Retailer-API/index.html

Comment: @Tanaike Did you find anything perhaps?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `Did you find anything perhaps?`, I am trying to find your expected method in the API from your provided document. When I could find and a solution, I would like to post an answer. I deeply apologize that I cannot still find your expected method.

Comment: Maybe a little off topic, but do you know how to use filtering on the bol search api, like price range, categories etc? Cannot find any info about it